# SWIG for Raspberry Pi CEC code produces undefined symbol error

Tags: python, c++, linux, raspberry-pi, swig

I want to create an interface between Python and the Raspberry Pi's CEC code (for example, [vc_cecservice.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/interface/vmcs_host/vc_cecservice.h)). I have created a small C++ file to begin this interface.

mycec.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <interface/vmcs_host/vc_cecservice.h>
#include <interface/vchiq_arm/vchiq_if.h>

int openClose() {
  VCHI_INSTANCE_T vchiq_instance;
  int res = vchi_initialise(&vchiq_instance);
  if (res != VCHIQ_SUCCESS) {
    printf("failed to open vchiq instance\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if (vchi_connect(NULL, 0, vchiq_instance) != 0) {
    printf( "VCHI connection failed\n" );
    return -1;
  }

  VCHI_CONNECTION_T *vchi_connection;
  vc_vchi_cec_init(vchiq_instance, &vchi_connection, 1);

  vc_vchi_cec_stop();

  return 0;
}
```

I am using SWIG to generate the CPython for this C++ file.

mycec.i:

```
%module mycec
%{
extern int openClose();
%}

extern int openClose();
```

I run the following bash script, on the Raspberry Pi, to compile the code.

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

swig -python mycec.i

g++ -c -fpic -L=/opt/vc/lib \
    -I=/usr/include/python2.7 \
        -I=/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I=/opt/vc/include \
    mycec.cpp mycec_wrap.c

g++ -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed -L=/opt/vc/lib \
    -I=/usr/include/python2.7 \
        -I=/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I=/opt/vc/include \
    -o _mycec.so mycec.o mycec_wrap.o \
    -lbcm_host -lvcos -lvchiq_arm
```

I then try to load it in `python`:

```
>>> import _mycec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./_mycec.so: undefined symbol: _Z16vc_vchi_cec_initP29opaque_vchi_instance_handle_tPP17vchi_connection_tj
```

The demangled name is `vc_vchi_cec_init(opaque_vchi_instance_handle_t*, vchi_connection_t**, unsigned int)`.

```
$ grep vc_vchi_cec_init /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so
Binary file /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so matches.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `extern "C"` around my `#includes`. This works:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {
#include <interface/vmcs_host/vc_cecservice.h>
#include <interface/vchiq_arm/vchiq_if.h>
}

// rest of program...
```